# Update to RegisterRoutes not reflected in MVC 5 code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a single controller, `HomeController` that I had setup with a default route that always went to `{action}`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
```

From here, I could navigate to `/status` or `/jobs` or other actions in the HomeController exactly as I expected.

I now have actions I want to logically separate into different controllers. I've added `FooController` with some actions:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Bar()
{
    return View();
}
```

Then I add new views:

~/Views/Foo/Index.cshtml (added as a non-partial view):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

This is the Foo index.
```

~Views/Foo/Bar.cshtml (added as a partial view):

```
This is the Foo/Bar action.
```

And finally, I set my default map route to target `{controller}/{action}` and created a new route for Foo that maps to a different URL. I set this before the Default:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Foo",
    url: "f/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Foo", action = "Index" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

With all this in-place, I launch my website and navigate to `/f/bar`, and I'm given a 404 error:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Not only that, but I can still navigate to `/status` and it correctly fires my `HomeController.Status()` method, whereas `/home/status` gives me a 404 error.

I cleaned the solution and re-built it; launched InPrivate mode to see if it was a cache issue; and tried a different browser. I'm constantly getting my old routes.

Comment: Could you try restarting the server to see if that helps? Routes get set when the application is started which is done by the server, not necessarily on every page refresh regardless if the libraries changed.

Comment: I'm debugging locally from Visual Studio. This is an extremely unsatisfying resolution, but quitting out of VS and restarting seems to have unstuck it.

Comment: Debugging on a local instance of IIS where it mounts the project. I don't know what the caching mechanisms used by the debugger but if you're getting the same port number every time you try to debug, that may be what was causing the issue. Restarting VS probably cleared out the local instance of IIS allow for the changes to take hold. Making changes in the Application_Start, such as route changes, can be frustrating at times.